# FSM, sum of products count

Tags: filter, signal-processing, vhdl

I have one problem with my VHDL project. Code below:

Reg module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reg is 
port(
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    d           : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    q           : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
);
end reg;

architecture arch of reg is

signal q_reg, q_next : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk, rst)
        begin
        if (rst ='1') then
                q_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            q_reg <= q_next;
        end if;
    end process;

    q_next <= d;
    q <= q_reg;

end arch;
```

Multiple module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity mul is
port (
    a : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    r : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
);
end mul;

architecture arch of mul is

signal result : signed (23 downto 0);
begin
        result <= signed(a) * signed(b);
        r        <= std_logic_vector(result);
end arch;
```

Adder module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity add is
port (
    a,b : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    s    : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
);
end add;

architecture arch of add is

signal result : signed(23 downto 0);
begin
    result <= signed(a) + signed(b);
    s        <= std_logic_vector(result);
end arch;
```

ALU module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is 
port (
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    data        : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cof     : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    y           : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
);
end alu;

architecture arch of alu is

signal mul_in_a               : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal mul_in_b               : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mul_out            : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

signal add_in_a, add_in_b : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal add_out                : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

signal reg_in, reg_out    : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

component mul
    port(
        a : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        r : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)   
    );
end component;

component add
    port(
        a : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        s : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component reg
    port(
        clk  : in std_logic;
        rst  : in std_logic;
        d     : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        q    : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
end component;

begin

b1:mul port map(
    a => mul_in_a,
    b => mul_in_b,
    r => mul_out
);

b2:add port map (
    a => add_in_a,
    b => add_in_b,
    s => add_out
);

b3:reg port map (
    clk => clk,
    rst => rst,
    d   => reg_in,
    q   => reg_out
);

mul_in_a <= data;
mul_in_b <= cof;

add_in_a <= mul_out;
add_in_b <= reg_out;

reg_in  <= add_out;

       y <= reg_out;
end arch;
```

Top module, with fsm:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity top is
port(
    clk   : in std_logic;
    rst   : in std_logic;
    rst_a     : in std_logic;
    data_in : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    data_out: out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    Yacc      :  out unsigned(3 downto 0)
);
end top;

architecture arch of top is

type STYPE is (load,count,result);
signal cof_alu_reg, cof_alu_next                              : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal dt_in_alu_reg,dt_in_alu_next                       : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal datao                              : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal state_reg, state_next          : STYPE;
signal adress_reg, adress_next                            :unsigned(3 downto 0);
signal data_out_reg, data_out_next : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

type cof_table is array ( 8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector( 15 downto 0);
type data_table is array ( 8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal Yacc_reg, Yacc_next :  unsigned(3 downto 0);
signal clr : std_logic;
signal datat                              : data_table;
signal coft                               : cof_table;

component alu
port(
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    data        : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cof     : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    y           : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
     );
end component;

begin

a1:alu port map (
    clk => clk,
    rst => clr,
    cof => cof_alu_reg,
    data => dt_in_alu_reg,
    y =>  datao
);

process(rst, clk)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        state_reg <= load;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        state_reg <= state_next;
    end if;
end process;



process(rst, clk)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        cof_alu_reg <= (others => '0');
        dt_in_alu_reg <= (others => '0');
        adress_reg <= "0000";
        data_out_reg <= (others => '0');
        Yacc_reg <= "0000";
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        cof_alu_reg <= cof_alu_next;
        dt_in_alu_reg <= dt_in_alu_next;
        adress_reg <= adress_next;
        data_out_reg <= data_out_next;
        Yacc_reg <= Yacc_next;
    end if;
end process;


process(state_reg, cof_alu_reg,dt_in_alu_reg,adress_reg,Yacc_reg,datao,clr)
begin
    state_next <= state_reg;
    cof_alu_next <= cof_alu_reg;
    dt_in_alu_next <= dt_in_alu_reg;
    adress_next <= adress_reg;
    data_out_next <= data_out_reg;
    Yacc_next <= Yacc_reg;

    coft(0) <= "0000000001101110";
    coft(1) <= "1111111110111011";
    coft(2) <= "1111111011000000";
    coft(3) <= "0000010001000101";
    coft(4) <= "0000100110100110";
    coft(5) <= "0000010001000101";
    coft(6) <= "1111111011000000";
    coft(7) <= "1111111110111011";
    coft(8) <= "0000000001101110";

    Yacc <= Yacc_reg;
    case state_reg is
        when load =>
        if adress_reg < "1001" then
            datat(to_integer(adress_reg)-1) <= data_in;
            Yacc_next <= adress_reg;
            adress_next <= adress_reg + "0001";
            state_next <= load;
        elsif adress_reg = "1001" then
            datat(to_integer(adress_reg)-1) <= data_in;
            Yacc_next <= adress_reg;
            adress_next <= "0000";
            state_next <= count;
        end if;

        when count =>
        if adress_reg < "1001" then
            dt_in_alu_next <= datat(to_integer(adress_reg)-1);
            cof_alu_next    <= coft(to_integer(adress_reg)-1);
            Yacc_next <= adress_reg;
            adress_next <= adress_reg + "0001";
            state_next <= count;
        elsif adress_reg = "1001" then
            dt_in_alu_next <= datat(to_integer(adress_reg-1));
            cof_alu_next    <= coft(to_integer(adress_reg)-1);
            state_next <= result;
            adress_next <= "0000";
            Yacc_next <= adress_reg;
        end if;

        when result =>
            data_out_next <= datao;
            Yacc_next <= adress_reg;
            adress_next <= adress_reg + "0001";
            state_next <= load;


        when others =>
            state_next <= load;

    end case;
end process;

    data_out    <= data_out_reg;


end arch;
```

This simple system counts a sum of products.  During first nine tacts of clock I get sampels from input, I use adress to increment the next position to save a sample. My problem is when system goes to nine tact of clock, the sample isn't save to memory which provides that final result is reducd. Anyone knows where the bug is ?

Comment: Some questions: Why are you writing `data_in` to `address - 1`? `datat` is addressed like a register, but it has no clock or corresponding process.

Comment: Memory is a simple table of std logic vector's. I am starting to write to first adress of memory at second tact of clock, so tht's why adress-1 is there.

Comment: So why don't you fix your counter to start at the right value? Sometimes it's needed to start at -1 or -2. But adding a -1 in index calculation forces synthesis to insert a subtractor (decrementer).

Comment: Is this intended for synthesis?  Can you demonstrate the short comings with simulation results? Provide a link, and someone can edit your question to add images. The idea is for both questions and answers to have value to other Stackoverflow  users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my recommendation.
Improvements:

- reduced async resets
- extracted dataflow from FSM
- introduced state idle for propper reset propagation
- corrected address calculation -> without -1
- defined coefficients as constant
- removed redundant registers

**Edit 1:**

I forgot that alu has a delay of 1 cycle. so you could count in state count up to 9 or insert a nop state between count and result.

Why is the calculation of datat indices wrong?
- After power up and after every reset, `adress_reg` is zero and `state` is load.
-> `if adress_reg < "1001" then` is the active branch in the current state (load)
-> `data_in` is written to index `to_integer("0000")-1)`
=> this is -1
=> simulation should give an out of range error

Why are the additional registers on `cof_alu_reg` and `dt_in_alu_reg` wrong?
- The FSM selects the appropriate coefficient and input for the alu in state count.
- These values are registered (1 cycle delay)
- The alu module performs the calculation with another cycle of delay
=> So after assigning the last input value for the alu there must be a 2 cycle delay before data_out_reg captures the result.

**Modified source code (not simulated):**

```
    architecture arch of top is

        type STYPE is (idle,load,count,nop,result);
        signal state_reg            : STYPE     := idle;
        signal state_next           : STYPE;

        signal address_rst          : std_logic;
        signal address_reg          : unsigned(3 downto 0)                      := (others => '0');

        type cof_table  is array (8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        type data_table is array (8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

        signal datat_en             : std_logic;
        signal datat                : data_table;

        signal cof_alu_next         : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        signal dt_in_alu_next       : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

        signal data_out_next        : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        signal data_out_en          : std_logic;
        signal data_out_reg         : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)     := (others => '0');

        constant coft                   : cof_table := (
            0 => "0000000001101110",
            1 => "1111111110111011",
            2 => "1111111011000000",
            3 => "0000010001000101",
            4 => "0000100110100110",
            5 => "0000010001000101",
            6 => "1111111011000000",
            7 => "1111111110111011",
            8 => "0000000001101110"
        );

    begin

        # no registers needed, because oft is constant and datat is already registered
        cof_alu_next    <= coft(to_integer(address_reg));
        dt_in_alu_next  <= datat(to_integer(address_reg));

        a1:alu port map (
                clk => clk,
                rst => clr,
                cof => cof_alu_next,
                data => dt_in_alu_next,
                y =>  data_out_next
        );

        process(rst, clk)
        begin
                if rst = '1' then
                        state_reg <= idle;
                elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                        state_reg <= state_next;
                end if;
        end process;

        # rewritten to synchronous registers
        process(clk)
        begin
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    # address counter
                    # count if reset is low
                    if (address_rst = '1') then
                        address_reg     <= (others => '0');
                    else
                        address_reg     <= address_reg + 1;
                    end if;

                    # datatable
                    # store data if enabled
                    if (datat_en = '1') then
                        datat(to_integer(address_reg)) <= data_in;
                    end if;

                    # result register
                    if (data_out_en = '1') then
                        data_out_reg    <= data_out_next;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process;


        process(state_reg, address_reg)
        begin
            state_next          <= state_reg;

            address_rst         <= '0';
            datat_en                <= '0';
            data_out_en         <= '0';

            case state_reg is
                when idle =>
                    address_rst <= '1';
                    state_next  <= load;                # add a condition if needed

                when load =>
                    datat_en        <= '1';
                    Yacc_next       <= address_reg;

                    if (address_reg = datat'high) then
                        address_rst <= '1';
                        state_next  <= count;
                    end if;

                when count =>
                    if (address_reg = datat'high) then
                        address_rst <= '1';
                        state_next  <= nop;
                    end if;

                when nop =>
                  state_next        <= result;

                when result =>
                    data_out_en     <= '1';
                    state_next      <= idle;        # if you want to go to count: assert address_rst in this state

                when others =>
                    state_next <= load;

            end case;
        end process;

        # outputs
        Yacc            <= address_reg when rising_edge(clk);       # delay Yacc output by one cycle (short form)
        data_out    <= data_out_reg;
    end arch;
```

Comment: Have you identified "where the bug is" in the questioner's design specification?  Is your version of `top` known to overcome that? If so, why?

Comment: @DavidKoontz I think the main problems are: false calculated indices and to many delay introduced by unnecessary 'pipeline' registers. The overall delay is not respected by FSM, which captures datao to early.

Comment: 'I think', 'too many delays'? Neither the questioner nor answerer have provided any simulation data, nor so much as a pipeline delay diagram. Even should the questioner be able to get his design working from your supposition, there is no value to other Stackoverflow users unless the questioner shows specifically what was changed and explains what the problem was.  I think you're probably right, but without proof your answer and my comment are opinions.